# Creating views in XML and Java then referencing and loading them later?

Tags: java, android, xml, view

In WPF (Microsoft land I know) you can define a control in XAML (xml-ish thing) along with the controls behaviour in codebehind (C#).

So in an XML file I want to be able to say something like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.mytestapp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

control:name="MyCustomControl"
 >

```
<Button />
<stuff>(...)</stuff>
</LinearLayout>
```

And also have a java source file called MyCustomControl which controls the behaviour of the control defined in the XML file.

Is there an equivalent for android with Java/XML? All I see are things involving custom attributes where you have to write out the entire control in Java still :-/

Answer (score 2):

Of course, Android is all about JAVA/XML. In fact, normally you design your UI(widgets/controls) in xml files(you can do it also programatically), and then you implement their behavior commonly on classes that extends Activity, an Android built in class. 
Check [this](https://www.google.com.cu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEIQFjAC&url=http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html&ei=rXF7Uf-nM6ae7Aa4loDIBQ&usg=AFQjCNF1ryIicTiyUZLMzEy80tQCU6Jr-w&bvm=bv.45645796,d.ZGU) out

Comment: That simply sets attributes, what I'd like to do is define an entire control in XML and java not just some attributes...

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate your android interfaces with XAML and Java, as you use to in WPF. 
Look at this link for more info about how to do it: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/Android-for-NET-Developers-Building-the-User-Interface.aspx

Comment: That simply sets attributes, what I'd like to do is define an entire control in XML and java not just some attributes